# How to make onDelete event for Doctrine 2 entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

For example:

We have entities PhotoGallery and Photo (one to many, cascade={"persist", "remove"}). If user delete PhotoGallery - all photos will be deleted automaticly from database. But photo files was not deleted.

How I can make onDelete function in entity Photo, that executed before/after deleting entity, and I can make deleting photo files from HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Lifecycle events](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html?highlight=postpersist#lifecycle-events) in your Photo model like below.

1. Add `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation in the class definition:

   ```
   /** @Entity @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
   class Photo{

       ....
   ```
2. You can use the `@preRemove` or `@postRemove` event in order delete the image from HDD:

   ```
   /** @PreRemove */
   public function preRemoveEvent()
   {
       // code to delete the image here
   }
   ```

The EntityManager and UnitOfWork trigger a bunch of events during the life-time of their registered entities. Said that, for example, `@preRemove` event is triggered before the EntityManager operation is executed:

```
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Finally, I have seen that you already declared the cascate `(one to many, cascade={"persist", "remove"})` as should be. The photo now will be removed from db and hdd.

Comment: Thanks its work. I have deleted photo-file name in entity property 'filename'. But for deleting, i need to get path to photo folder that exist in service locator. How i can get access to service locator from entity? Is it ok if i will delete photo files from entity, not from repository etc?

Comment: What do you mean with "service locator"?

Comment: It's $this->getServiceLocator()->get('NAME') in controller.

Answer (score 0):

A very clean and comfortable approach is to use the Uploadable Doctrine behavior extension.

You can find everything about it in the docs:

> Uploadable behavior provides the tools to manage the persistence of files with Doctrine 2, including automatic handling of moving, renaming and removal of files and other features.
>
> Features:
>
> - Extension moves, removes and renames files according to configuration automatically
> - Lots of options: Allow overwrite, append a number if file exists, filename generators, post-move callbacks, etc.
> - It can be extended to work not only with uploaded files, but with files coming from any source (an URL, another file in the same server, etc).
> - Validation of size and mime type

https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/uploadable.md

Comment: Why use an extension for this scenario? Doctrine can manage it natively just with a few lines of code.

Comment: Because handling uploaded files is not always a simple scenario. This extension solves so many other problems associated with it. I'm not saying it could not be done with custom code (witch is often less clean), I'm just recommending to consider this well-tried solution.